I need a bubble which should work exactly like the one in uber driver app. Does Flutter alone supports this?
when slide button in the first picture first picture is submitted then navigate to google maps MapUtils.openMap(rideData['sourceDropAddress']["latitudeAddress"], rideData['sourceDropAddress']["longitudeAddress"]); when navigate to google maps is happened then keep the app in the background and do ref.read(rideProvider).notifyRideStatus(RideStatus.rideInitiated); context.replace('/${DriverRoute.home.name}'); like in the second picture second picture also start bubble service show that bubble on the google maps like in the third picture third picture and app must be in the background and when tap on the bubble then it should open the app.
I have tried awesome_bubble, dash_bubble, system_alert_window, flutter_overlay_window, flutter_overlay_apps and I have also tried integrating with platform-specific code (native Android in this case) but i cannot achieve the exact functionality which is required. Does Flutter alone enough to achieve this behaviour? If 'yes' then what is the solution? If 'no' then how can i achieve this natively?
